# Console.WriteLine() vs. Console.WriteLine(string.Empty)

Tags: c#

In one of our application I've come across some lines like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
```

I checked whether it makes any difference if I just write:

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

But the output is the same (as expected).

What's "best practice" in this example? Are there any situations where it's necessary to pass an empty `string` instead of not passing any parameter?

Comment: How much does this actually matter?

Comment: It's a matter of preference I guess, but technically there is no difference.

Comment: You forgot to mention `Console.Write(System.Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: Doesnt newline make it do 2 new lines not 1?

Comment: And also `Console.WriteLine("EMPTY LINE".Substring(0, 0));`.

Comment: @BugFinder - it would if it were `WriteLine`, but fubo's used `Write`.

Comment: as Callum said it doesn't really matter but I'd just go for Console.WriteLine() - less code in eyes

Comment: Missed that :P @Enigmativity

Comment: If there is a "Best Practice" on this then someone is being paid too much or there is a lack of focus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`WriteLine()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,360) is implemented like this:

```
public virtual void WriteLine() {
    Write(CoreNewLine);
}
```

[`WriteLine(string)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,452) however is implemented like this:

```
public virtual void WriteLine(String value) {
    if (value==null) {
        WriteLine();
    }
    else {
        // We'd ideally like WriteLine to be atomic, in that one call
        // to WriteLine equals one call to the OS (ie, so writing to 
        // console while simultaneously calling printf will guarantee we
        // write out a string and new line chars, without any interference).
        // Additionally, we need to call ToCharArray on Strings anyways,
        // so allocating a char[] here isn't any worse than what we were
        // doing anyways.  We do reduce the number of calls to the 
        // backing store this way, potentially.
        int vLen = value.Length;
        int nlLen = CoreNewLine.Length;
        char[] chars = new char[vLen+nlLen];
        value.CopyTo(0, chars, 0, vLen);
        // CoreNewLine will almost always be 2 chars, and possibly 1.
        if (nlLen == 2) {
            chars[vLen] = CoreNewLine[0];
            chars[vLen+1] = CoreNewLine[1];
        }
        else if (nlLen == 1)
            chars[vLen] = CoreNewLine[0];
        else
            Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(CoreNewLine, 0, chars, vLen * 2, nlLen * 2);
        Write(chars, 0, vLen + nlLen);
    }
}
```

If you call it with a `null` string, then you get the same result as for `WriteLine()` without arguments (plus an additional method call). The logic when passing a non-null string however is a bit more complex.

For `string.Empty` this will allocate a new character array of length 2 and copy the new line character to that.

This is generally not expensive but still somewhat redundant if you don’t want to print anything. Especially for *fixed* calls to `Console.WriteLine` it does not make any sense to pass `string.Empty` there.

You should prefer `Console.WriteLine()` over `Console.WriteLine(string.Empty)` if alone for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to use the more readable `Console.WriteLine();`.

Even though there's no semantic difference, you'll execute [unnecessary code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,5238cceaebfeaa74) if you write `Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);`:

```
public virtual void WriteLine(String value) {

    if (value==null) {
        WriteLine();
    }
    else {
        // We'd ideally like WriteLine to be atomic, in that one call
        // to WriteLine equals one call to the OS (ie, so writing to 
        // console while simultaneously calling printf will guarantee we
        // write out a string and new line chars, without any interference).
        // Additionally, we need to call ToCharArray on Strings anyways,
        // so allocating a char[] here isn't any worse than what we were
        // doing anyways.  We do reduce the number of calls to the 
        // backing store this way, potentially.
        int vLen = value.Length;
        int nlLen = CoreNewLine.Length;
        char[] chars = new char[vLen+nlLen];
        value.CopyTo(0, chars, 0, vLen);
        // CoreNewLine will almost always be 2 chars, and possibly 1.
        if (nlLen == 2) {
            chars[vLen] = CoreNewLine[0];
            chars[vLen+1] = CoreNewLine[1];
        }
        else if (nlLen == 1)
            chars[vLen] = CoreNewLine[0];
        else
            Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(CoreNewLine, 0, chars, vLen * 2, nlLen * 2);
        Write(chars, 0, vLen + nlLen);
    }
    /*
    Write(value);  // We could call Write(String) on StreamWriter...
    WriteLine();
    */
}
```

**There's a buffer allocation and string copy in there.** It would be better if they had written `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))` but for some reason they haven't.

Whereas the simpler way [is just](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,d2497198aa8f74c0):

```
public virtual void WriteLine() {
    Write(CoreNewLine);
}
```

(`CoreNewLine` is a `char[]`)

Comment: `but for some reason they haven't` - probably because no-one ever said, "Oh, my program just went 0.0001ms slower because of that darned buffer allocation."

Comment: @Enigmativity probably, yes ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatsoever for me on the technical side. It is just the way the developer find it comfortable and more readable. For me, `Console.WriteLine()` is more intuitive that it is writing an empty line, while `Console.WriteLine(String.Empty)` makes me stop and think for a second (Maybe less).

Any other variation would be, IMO, an act of making code fancy and not to be used in professional production code.

Answer (score 1):

From the reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx)

WriteLine(String) :
Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.

WriteLine() :
Writes the current line terminator to the standard output stream.

It would seem that it makes absolutely no (visual) difference (implementation, as another answer has mentioned is a different matter) and would depend on user preference although I'm not sure I know many people who prefer unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on [tryroslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/)

C# code:

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        Console.WriteLine();      
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Generate IL code:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 19 (0x13)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
        IL_000c: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0011: nop
        IL_0012: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2064
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

So line `Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);` gets value from `string.Empty` and pass it to function. Better is `Console.WriteLine()` less operations.

Comment: Although writing to the console is so slow that no one will notice the difference.

Comment: Having one more IL operation to read a static member is not really reason enough to prefer one call over another. Readability of the call is a much more compelling argument, and if you want to argue by internals (IL code etc), you should look at the implementations of the methods you are calling.